# How to anonymize DWG documents in AutoCAD?

Tags: privacy, autocad

Sometimes, when sending DWG document, you need to do so anonymously. When answering a call for bids, e.g.

However, AutoCAD automatically save a “last-saved-by” metadata field, which contains the login of the last person who, well, saved the file. Is there a way to edit this field such that it returns something else that a name<sup>*</sup>?

---

<sup>*</sup> Other than creating a new user with a meaningless name, obviously.

Comment: save DWG as PDF